# What is an extension of an inner product space?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, geometric-algebras

Chapter 5 of Alan Macdonald's "Linear and Geometric Algebra" begins by saying,

> The geometric algebra $\mathbb{G}^n $ is an extension of the inner product space $\mathbb{R}^n.$

What is an extension of an inner product space?

Answer (score 3):

I mean *extension* in the usual English sense: $\mathbb{R}$, its vectors and its operations (scalar product, vector addition, inner product) are contained in $\mathbb{G}$.

Comment: Awesome to see the author respond in real time

Answer (score 1):

According to [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/extension), "**extension**" can mean "an instance of enlarging the scope of something". And according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), an "**inner product space**" is "a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) with an additional [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) called an **inner product**" and while this is alluded to early on, [later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Euclidean_vector_space) it clearly states "the [real *n*-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space) ${\displaystyle \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$ with the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is an inner product space".

Putting this together, an "extension of the inner product space $\mathbb R^n$" means taking the vectors and inner product (standardly the dot product) of $\mathbb R^n$, and somehow enlarging the scope. That's a little vague, but the default interpretation would be that, at minimum: $\mathbb G^n$ is a [superset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) of $\mathbb R^n$, and you can still take the inner (dot) product of the $\mathbb R^n$ vectors inside of $\mathbb G^n$. (The previous chapter on $\mathbb G^3$ and the later text in this chapter clarifies what $\mathbb G^n$ is more precisely than this one-sentence summary.)